# angularjs TypeError: undefined is not a function factory

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I'm in the middle of playing around with angularjs. I'm trying to simply pull data from a json file. When I run my code the file shows up in the network, but the data doesn't show up on the page and I get the following error in my console:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function at Ob
>   (lib/angular-1-2/angular.min.js:14:6)

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var Services = angular.module('Services', ['ngResource']);
Services.factory('reportFactory', function($http){
    console.log(REPORT_LIST_URL);
    return{
        getReports: function(callback){
            $http.get(REPORT_LIST_URL).success(callback);
        }
    }
});

function ReportsCtrl($scope, $http, reportFactory) {
    $scope.reportsList = [];
    console.log($scope.reportsList);
    console.log("Get report list from json file");
    console.log("before the factory");
    reportFactory.getReports(function(data){
       $scope.reportsList = data;
    });
}
```

example of the json file

```
{
  "Reports": {
    "Productivity": [
      {
        "name": "Productivity Summary",
        "value": "Productivity"
      },
      {
        "name": "Time Summary",
        "value": "TimeSummary"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that both factory and controller is in same app.
I did some refactor in factory so that it will get more reusable.
Small changes if factory. Now getReports will return a promise. We can call our function when promise gets resolved.

```
var Services = angular.module('Services', ['ngResource']);
Services.factory('reportFactory', function($http){
    console.log(REPORT_LIST_URL);
    return{
        getReports: function(){
            return $http.get(REPORT_LIST_URL); //returning promise
        }
    }
});

Services.controller('ReportsCtrl',function($scope, $http, reportFactory) {
    $scope.reportsList = [];
    console.log($scope.reportsList);
    console.log("Get report list from json file");
    console.log("before the factory");
    reportFactory.getReports().then(
    //success callback
     function(data){ 
       $scope.reportsList = data;
    },
    //error callback
    function(data){
       $scope.reportsList = data;
    });
});
```

Hopefully this will help you, Thanks.

Comment: You forgot the `return` in `getReports`.